# Embed applet into html page issue

Tags: java, html, path, applet

I am having trouble to embed a simple applet. I think the settings for relative/absolute path to the class file name are the problem. I've tried many different ways to do it but none have worked. With only one exception. If I place the indexApplet.html file inside the bin folder, then it works. But I would like to keep indexApplet.html outside of it. I will really appreciate any help for this matter.

Here is my html code and folder structure:

```
[code]
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Java Game</title>

</head>

<body>

<applet code="test/bin/first/hello.class"  width="800" height="600" alt="Java Game" title="Go and Play"></applet>

</body>
</html>
[/code]
```

The class file is located at: C:\Users\Valentin\workspace\test\bin\first

I would like to have the indexApplet.html file outside of test folder.

Comment: So you have got your `indexApplet.html` in folder `C:\Users\Valentin\workspace` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're viewing the applet from `C:\Users\Valentin\workspace` and the class `hello` is declared in the `first` package then you need to add the `codebase` attribute:

```
<applet code="first.hello.class" width="800" height="600" codebase="test/bin">
```

Read: [Using applet, object and embed Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html)

Comment: Is `hello` declared in a `first` package?

Comment: What do you mean by that? "declared". The file hello.class is located in the folder labeled first.

Comment: does it begin with `package first;`? - post your `hello.java` if its not too big

Comment: package first;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class hello extends Applet {
 
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError

hello (wrong name: first/hello)

Comment: Is `hello.class` definitely located in `C:\Users\Valentin\workspace\test\bin\first`? and are u running (appletviewer say) from `C:\Users\Valentin\workspace`?

Comment: It is OK now. It was my mistake into html code. I forgot to add a forward slash. This is great. I realy appreciate your big help.